# Activity moved to back starting activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I find it difficult to start new activity using application staying in the background.
Here is my code:

```
public class App1 extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        registerReceiver(batteryInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver batteryInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent("App2.intent.action.Launch");
            intent.putExtra("startedByApp", true);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
}


public class App2 extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TEST 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

When App1 is in the foreground it works fine.
When App1 is in the background (moveToBack) it shows "TEST", but it doesn't start App2 (there is no "TEST 2" on my screen.

Guys, can you help me?

Comment: why don't you try Log.d() instead of Toast? Toast generally isn't very good as a debugging tool, especially when you're using getApplicationContext()

Comment: may be you need a flag `intent.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Comment: @mfrankli:
it's good idea - i'm a beginner programmer, i'd like to use it.

Comment: @Sunny Please add your suggestion as an answer so this doesn't show up in the "unanswered" list

Answer (score 1):

You need a flag `intent.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`